# Plumbing supplies and california prop 65

Tags: plumbing

Are there any plumbing supplies which do **not** contain any chemicals known to the state of California under proposition 65? If yes, where can I buy them? If not, why?

EDIT: by "plumbing supplies" I meant mostly pipes, push-to-fit connectors, gaskets and the likes, for application to **drinking** water. To be even more explicit, I recently bought and installed a reverse osmosis system, to have safer drinking water for my family. Looking at most of the pipes and push-to-connect fittings, all of them have the prop 65 warning *This product contains chemicals known to the State of California to cause cancer and birth defects or other reproductive harm*. Now you may dismiss this with "those paranoid Californians, the other authorities know better", yet maybe a small amount of truth can be in that. Moreover, tell to the people of Flint, MI about trusting the authority.

Therefore, I would like to use products known to **not** contain any of the prop 65 chemicals. I could not find any, hence my question (which is not purchasing advice): do such things exist? If not, there must be a reason, so why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of plumbing supplies are you talking about (piping, glues, cleaners)? And why do you care? (Shopping advice is generally off-topic here...)

Comment: Do a bit of research on prop 65 and then come back and tell us what your concerns actually are. If you randomly use prop 65 as a basis for living your life, you're either in a cave or a bubble.

Comment: Sorry to say but if you eat or drink, you will ingest prop 65 items.  If you breathe you will inhale prop 65 items.   Do not see a dentist or doctor medications from them, supplies used by them make the list.   Do not drive gas, diesel or electric all prop 65.   As commented by User95050 look at the list and cringe either on how it even exists or how we all are alive.  Great for lawyers and driving costs up.

Comment: @spicetraders I have not seen prop65 warnings on food or drinks sold in California. Where is it written that food and drinks are exempt from labeling? They are either exempt or don't contain the chemicals as you claim. I will not comment of breathing, driving, dentists and drugs. since it's off topic. Finally, regarding driving costs up, where are the plumbing supplies with higher costs that do not contain those chemicals?

Comment: The whole point is your putting the water in a cup that has a chance of P65 chemicals.  As well as all the other items listed are filling your life with P65 items.  Only new items must be marked and then only certain items qualify.  But as you wish, copper I have not seen on the list, but not sure how you can make the joining of the pieces.   As for cost shop at an adjacent state and compare prices.

Comment: It's worth noting that testosterone and estrogen are both on the proposition 65 list - should everyone in the state have a prop. 65 warning tattooed on their foreheads?.  That law appeared to be a good idea, but has actually become a  complete fiasco.  Virtually every product sold in the state has the warning on it, so it has become pointless.  It's kind of like the "Don't use this toaster in the bathtub" on steroids.  Oh, sorry - steroids are probably on the list too.